# How to use tensorflow.estimator to load only part of layer parameters of the pre training model

Tags: tensorflow, bert-language-model

I want to add some additional layers behind the Bert model, when loading the pre_training model, delete these layers from the list that needs to be loaded, but it fails, and if still reports that cannot find the parameter. use tensorflow 1.14.0
Can someone tell me how to do it? Thanks very much!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kcdc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMMYK.png)

```
python
final_hidden_shape = modeling.get_shape_list(final_hidden, 
     expected_rank=3)
batch_size = final_hidden_shape[0]
seq_length = final_hidden_shape[1]
hidden_size = final_hidden_shape[2]
lstm=tf.keras.layers.LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True, 
     return_state=True,name='cls/squad/mylstm') #this my layer

final_hidden, final_memory_state, final_carry_state = lstm(final_hidden)
output_weights = tf.get_variable(
     "cls/squad/output_weights", [2, hidden_size],
     initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02))

output_bias = tf.get_variable(
     "cls/squad/output_bias", [2], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

final_hidden_matrix = tf.reshape(final_hidden,
                                   [batch_size * seq_length, hidden_size])
logits = tf.matmul(final_hidden_matrix, output_weights, transpose_b=True)
     logits = tf.nn.bias_add(logits, output_bias)


tvars = tf.trainable_variables() #获得所有可训练的权重参数
    tvars=tvars[:198]  #here I want delet the layer that I add
    print(tvars)

initialized_variable_names = {}
scaffold_fn = None
if init_checkpoint:
      (assignment_map, initialized_variable_names) = modeling.get_assignment_map_from_checkpoint(tvars, init_checkpoint)
      print(assignment_map)
      print(initialized_variable_names)
if use_tpu:
        # def tpu_scaffold():
        #   tf.train.init_from_checkpoint(init_checkpoint, assignment_map)
        #   sess = tf.Session()
        #   saver = tf.train.Saver(tvars)
        #   saver.restore(sess,init_checkpoint)
        #   return tf.train.Scaffold()

        # scaffold_fn = tpu_scaffold
        pass
else:
        # pass
        tf.train.init_from_checkpoint(init_checkpoint, assignment_map)
```

I got the following error

```
    INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from tmp/squad2.0_base/model.ckpt-6000
    I0515 06:17:15.064314 139686871394176 saver.py:1280] Restoring parameters 
    from tmp/squad2.0_base/model.ckpt-6000
    2020-05-15 06:17:15.907003: W 
    tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1412] (One-time 
    warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=-- 
    tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that 
    envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA 
    is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line 
    flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
    2020-05-15 06:17:15.956482: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1502] 
    OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_v2_ops.cc:184 : Not found: Key 
    cls/squad/mylstm/bias not found in checkpoint
    ERROR:tensorflow:Error recorded from training_loop: Restoring from checkpoint 
    failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key that is 
    missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the 
    graph 
    expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

    Key cls/squad/mylstm/bias not found in checkpoint
     [[node save/RestoreV2 (defined at run_squad.py:1278) ]]

    Original stack trace for 'save/RestoreV2':
    File "run_squad.py", line 1350, in <module>
     tf.app.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
    packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
     _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
     _run_main(main, args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in 
    _run_main
     sys.exit(main(argv))
    File "run_squad.py", line 1278, in main
    estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=num_train_steps)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
    packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 
    2871, in train
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
    packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 367, in 
    train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
    packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1158, in 
    _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
    packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1192, in 
    _train_model_default
     saving_listeners)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
    packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1480, in 
     _train_with_estimator_spec
     log_step_count_steps=log_step_count_steps) as mon_sess:
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
     packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 584, in 
     MonitoredTrainingSession
     stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
     packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1007, in 
     __init__
     stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
     packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 725, in 
     __init__
     self._sess = _RecoverableSession(self._coordinated_creator)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
     packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1200, in 
      __init__
    _WrappedSession.__init__(self, self._create_session())
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
     packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1205, in 
      _create_session
     return self._sess_creator.create_session()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
    packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 871, in 
     create_session
     self.tf_sess = self._session_creator.create_session()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
     packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 638, in 
     create_session
     self._scaffold.finalize()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
      packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 237, in 
     finalize
     self._saver.build()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
     packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 837, in build
     self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
     packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 875, in _build
     build_restore=build_restore)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
     packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 502, in _build_internal
     restore_sequentially, reshape)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
     packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 381, in 
    _AddShardedRestoreOps
     name="restore_shard"))
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
     packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 328, in _AddRestoreOps
     restore_sequentially)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
     packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 575, in bulk_restore
     return io_ops.restore_v2(filename_tensor, names, slices, dtypes)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
     packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1696, in restore_v2
     name=name)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
     packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in 
     _apply_op_helper
      op_def=op_def)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
    packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
     packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3616, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
    packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2005, in __init__
     self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

    E0515 06:17:15.972786 139686871394176 error_handling.py:70] Error recorded 
       from training_loop: Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely 
    due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the 
    checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based 
    on the checkpoint. Original error:
```

Comment: Please post your code, not image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Thank you for reminding me， I'm new here， I've edited the question again !

Comment: It seems like you have not assigned anything to `init_checkpoint` and you are trying to train the model by using it.